# How to report a bug found on python 3.7.4 package by anaconda default channel?

Tags: python-3.x, anaconda

After creating a conda environment with python 3.7.4, I noticed some extra rpinting in the stdout. I realized the root cause was on python 3.7.4 package provided by anaconda default channel (not on python itself)

The bug is on `lib/python3.7/_sysconfigdata_m_linux_x86_64-linux-gnu.py` file, for the specific package:

Name                      Version              Build         Channel
python                    3.7.4                h265db76_0    default

I would like to know where can I find the source code for the python 3.7 recipe so that i can submit a patch for it.

Downgrading python to 3.7.3 or earlier is a workaround, but it is important to fix the latest too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just found the repository with python recipes for Anaconda:
https://github.com/AnacondaRecipes/python-feedstock

The python-feedstock was a little bit misleading :)